# Selenium webdriver recognizes button but does not click

Tags: button, selenium-webdriver

I am working on automation of an application written using JavaScript. I wrote code in Java to recognize a web button. This button becomes enabled only if an option in a listbox is selected. So I do that too.

Code excerpts from application:

Issue: It recognizes the button but does not click it.

my code n Java

```
    //Assign web element for listbox and click on item
    WebElement listitem=driver.findElement(By.id("yui-rec0"));
    listitem.click();

    //Click on Submit to complete login
    WebElement selectProfile=driver.findElement(By.id("f4_btnSelect"));
    selectProfile.click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should always use **WebdriverWait** class in order to invoke any click events. When the listitem is initially ticked, there is a very slight delay before the selectProfile item becomes clickable.

```
WebElement selectProfile=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("f4_btnSelect"))));
selectProfile.click();
```

Lemme know if it works

**Edit**
I am updating the result for others in accordance to user3856308 response:

```
WebElement selectProfile=(new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.f‌​indElement(By.id("f4_btnSelect")))); 
selectProfile.click();
```

Comment: //Click on Submit to complete login
WebElement selectProfile=(new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("f4_btnSelect"))));
  selectProfile.click();

Comment: Ops. Yea I can see I forgot to initialize the Webdriverwait class. Anyways glad I could help :)